# GraphX ShortestPaths from org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.ShortestPaths

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, shortest-path, spark-graphx

In spark scala, I have a weighted graph of the following form :

```
- Edges:    Edge(65281061,65281095,(8915415,229.81473441303393))
- Vertices: (65352257,(0.0,0.0,Map(254396716)))
```

The edges contains the distance (In this case; 229.81473441303393)

I want to calculate the shortest distance from sourceId = 4177086687 vertice to every other vertice in the graph.

I am running the following function:

```
ShortestPaths.run(weightedRoadGraph, Seq(sourceId))
```

and it returns me an integer as the distance (I assume it is the number of nodes).

```
+----------+------------------+
|        _1|                _2|
+----------+------------------+
|  65308287|{4177086687 -> 28}|
|  65310806|{4177086687 -> 38}|
|  65319968|{4177086687 -> 39}|
+----------+------------------+
```

I want to sum the distance from the edges and get a total sum distance.
I want the output to be the total distance, rather than an integer.

Thanks in advance!